# iOS - improve insert performance SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

How can i improve performance insert data in SQLite Database.

The Amount of data is 30000 Records. The Code is:

```
- (void)insertBranchDB:branchlistArray
{
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (Branch *branch in branchlistArray) {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"insert or replace into Branch (id, lang, lat, lng, province_id, district_id, optional, bus, status, name, address, contact, telephone, remark, province_name, district_name, lastupdate) values (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",branch._id,branch.lang,branch.lat,branch.lng,branch.province_id,branch.district_id,branch.optional,branch.bus,branch.status,branch.name,branch.address,branch.contact,branch.telephone,branch.remark,branch.province_name,branch.district_name,branch.lastupdate];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Completed to Add Branch %d",count);
            count;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to Add Branch %d",count);
            count;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can move the definition of `insertSQL` and assignment to `insert_stmt` outside the loop.  This would mean using placeholders for the values ("?"), and filling them inside the loop, using the `sqlite3_bind_*` family of functions.

Comment: Avi's point may have a modest impact on performance (the significant savings is in using transactions), but you should adopt his pattern for other reasons. Specifically using `?` placeholder in your SQL and then use `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` to bind values is much safer and more robust. If someone tried to insert a value that, itself, contained a double quote, your existing SQL would fail. Using `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` will solve that problem. And, as Avi says, if you "prepare" once, and then "bind", "step", and "reset" for each loop, it will also be modestly more efficient.

Comment: By the way, if you find the calling of `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` for each of those columns a bit unwieldy, you can consider using something like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which can simplify that process.

Answer (score 1):

You'll see a dramatic performance improvement if you use transactions. So before you perform all of the `INSERT` statements, perform a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and at the end, perform a `COMMIT` (or `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `END TRANSACTION`).

See the [Transactions](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) discussion at http://sqlite.org.

Answer (score -2):

Look to insert the rows in bulk

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename'
SELECT 'data1' AS 'column1', 'data2' AS 'column2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'data1', 'data2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'data1', 'data2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'data1', 'data2'
```

So in your case:

```
INSERT INTO 'Branch'
SELECT 'id' AS 'column1', 'lang' AS 'column2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'row_one_.branch._id', 'row_one_.branch.lang'
UNION ALL SELECT 'row_two_.branch._id', 'row_two_.branch.lang'
UNION ALL SELECT 'row_three_.branch._id', 'row_three_.branch.lang'
```

look at this post [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

Comment: Then loop to 500 then run command, then compile the next 500, etc.